# VBA coding Copy Paste

Tags: vba, excel

I want to copy data from two xls files, Rahul.xls and Rohit.xls and paste them in a master file "Macro.xls"

The code is copy pasting Rahul.xls but when pasting Rohit.xls it is overlapping the data, resulting that all the data from Rahul.xls is gone and i can only see the data from Rohit.xls.

Second, is that it is not closing the source files after copy-pasting.

Can anyone help me in amending this code so that

- Rohit's data will come after Rahul's data
- after copy pasting Rahul's data the sheet will close automatically

  ```
  Sub OpenCopyPaste()

  ' open the source workbook and select the source sheet

      Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Rahul.xls"

      Sheets("Case Tracker").Select

      ' copy the source range

      Sheets("Case Tracker").Range("A:J").Select

      Selection.Copy

      ' select current workbook and paste the values starting at A1

      Windows("Macro.xls").Activate

      Sheets("Sheet1").Select

      Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Select

      ActiveSheet.Paste

      Application.CutCopyMode = False

      ActiveWorkbook.Save

      Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Rohit.xls"

      Sheets("Case Tracker").Select

      ' copy the source range

      Sheets("Case Tracker").Range("A:J").Select

      Selection.Copy

      ' select current workbook and paste the values starting at A1

      Windows("Macro.xls").Activate

      Sheets("Sheet1").Select

      Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Select

      ActiveSheet.Paste

      Application.CutCopyMode = False

      ActiveWorkbook.Save

  End Sub
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The code is overwriting the data in Sheet1 range starting at A1 after it opens the second file. Think of a way to find the end of the range and start the new data there.

```
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Rohit.xls"

    Sheets("Case Tracker").Select

    ' copy the source range

    Sheets("Case Tracker").Range("A:J").Select
    Selection.Copy

    ' select current workbook and paste the values starting at A1

    Windows("Macro.xls").Activate

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select

    ' the code is overwriting the data in Sheet1 range starting at A1
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Select 

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    ActiveWorkbook.Save
```

For closing a workbook, I believe it is just as simple as:

```
    Workbooks(fileName).Close
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Hopefully it's what you need, but if not I hope that it at least can get you on the path to the answer. Cheers.

```
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Rahul.xls"

    Sheets("Case Tracker").Select

    ' copy the source range

    Sheets("Case Tracker").Range("A:J").Select

    Selection.Copy

    ' select current workbook and paste the values starting at A1

        Windows("Macro.xls").Activate

        Sheets("Sheet1").Select

        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Select

        ActiveSheet.Paste

        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        ActiveWorkbook.Save

        workbooks("Rahul.xls").close workbooks("Rahul.xls").saved=true

        Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Rohit.xls"

        Sheets("Case Tracker").Select

        ' copy the source range

        Sheets("Case Tracker").Range("A:J").Select
        Selection.Copy

        ' select current workbook and paste the values starting at A1

        Windows("Macro.xls").Activate

        Sheets("Sheet1").Select


        'Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Select-take this bit and replace it with the following

     emptyrow=worksheetfunction.counta(sheets("sheet1").range("A")) 'you can use any column to reference, one with continuous data is the best
     sheets("Sheet1").cells(emptyrow,1).select

        ActiveSheet.Paste

        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        ActiveWorkbook.Save

        workbooks("Rohit.xls").close workbooks("Rohit.xls").saved=true

        End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @USFBS... i think there is some error... as i am unable to execute this code. Showing error on Sub "OpenCopyPaste()

Comment: there may be a problem in my syntax. I have written similar code to this, but in mine i always set the file that is to be opened as a variable (ex. `set b1 = workbooks.open (filename)`) . Also, I mistakenly wrote `.Saved = True` as `.Save = True`. To clarify, it should be `.Saved` some tweaks there should yield the results you seek.

Comment: It is  Sub OpenCopyPaste() not  Sub "OpenCopyPaste()

Comment: Thanks for helping me out pals. However while running this code, debug is on emptyrow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("sheet1").Range("A")) . Can someone help. why?

Comment: If the error is showing up on that line, then you may need to define the workbook name before the sheet and range (so something like adding`emptyrow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Workbooks(<workbookname>).Sheets("sheet1").Range("A"))`)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a variable to define the last used Row in the destination Sheet and addedd plus one at the desire Range :

```
    Sub CopySheets()
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Rahul.xls"
    'Variable to the last available row
    Dim lLastRow As Long

    Sheets("Case Tracker").Range("A:J").Copy Destination:=Windows("Macro.xls").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Rohit.xls"

    'Retrieve the last used row in the destination
    lLastRow = Workbooks("Macro").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Workbooks("Macro").Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    'Use the Lastrow variable aded to the range of the destination + 1 (the next empty row)
    Sheets("Case Tracker").Range("A:J").Copy Destination:=Windows("Macro.xls").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & lLastRow + 1)

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Workbooks("Macro").Save
    Workbooks("Macro").Close

    End Sub
```

---

meanwhile in your urgency, you could only use the

`Dim lLastRow As Long`

and the other line

`lLastRow = Workbooks("Macro").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Workbooks("Macro").Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`

and only add the variable modifying the second destination like this:

`Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & lLastRow + 1)`

in your original code

Comment: Hi @Zegad, I tried this however it is popping an error "Object dowsn't support this property or method".... any idea what this is all about

Comment: Its untested but if you  tell me which line the debug send you I could correct it. see edit